# How to substitute oranges in a mango mousse recipe?

Tags: substitutions, oranges, mousse

I'm looking for a recipe for orange mousse without eggs, but hopefully with gelatine. I've tried to search for some recipes on google but didn't really find anything too good. I have a very delicious recipe for mango mousse that I found on google that I've tried a lot of times. It would be great if someone could guide me with substituting it with orange rind/juice. I know that Orange recipes can become a bit bitter if not handled properly.

Here's the Mango mousse recipe, which is a part of a mango mousse cake.

- 450 gr. mango
- 75 gr. sugar
- 2 tablespoons lemon juice
- 3 1/2 teaspoons gelatin
- 500 ml. heavy cream.

Puree the mango flesh with the sugar and lemon juice. Strain to remove fiber from mango.
Put one third of the mango puree into the pot and stir in the gelatin. Let the gelatin soften, and warm over low heat, stirring until dissolves. Remove and add remaining mango puree, and allow to cool. While cooling, whip the cream. Stir in mango into the whipped cream, transfer into containers and chill.

Comment: I would never give up a mango mousse for an orange one.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: I know, its so so delicious. But I want to try to make orange mousse and fill chocolate cups with it because orange and chocolate work so well together.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a strategy from a orange olive oil cake that I make.  Cut about 1/2 inch off the ends of oranges.  Then quarter the oranges.  Place them in a pot of water, then bring to the boil.  Drain and repeat 3 to 4 times.  This reduces the bitterness of the pith.  Now, add 4 cups of water and 1 cup of sugar to the pot.  Add the oranges and bring to a simmer.  Cook until they are tender, 30 to 40 minutes, then drain (you can reserve the light syrup for another use).  Blend the cooked oranges in a food processor or blender.  Use 450 grams in your recipe (strained), eliminate the lemon.  Let us know (with a comment, or an answer to your own question if you choose a different approach) if it worked.